# After I used free() function along with Null pointer ... The program is still crashing

Tags: c, for-loop, nullpointerexception, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Why is this program crashing? Help me have a clear understanding behind  the logic behind free(ptr); ptr = 0; too.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int *ptr;

    ptr = (int *) malloc(6 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the value of %d element is :", i);
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
         free(ptr); 
         ptr = 0;
}
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("The value of %d element is : %d\n", i, ptr[i]);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you `free` the pointer and use it again in the next iteration then a crash is very reasonable behaviour. Move the `free` to be just before the `return` and remove the `ptr=0`.

Comment: Once you have freed the memory you can't de-reference it. And that's it. What makes you think you can?

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the value of %d element is :", i);
    scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
     free(ptr); 
     ptr = 0;
}
```

you freed the allocated memory

```
     free(ptr);
```

and set the pointer `ptr` equal to `NULL`.

```
     ptr = 0;
```

So in next iterations of the loop and within the following loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    printf("The value of %d element is : %d\n", i, ptr[i]);   
}
```

you are trying to access memory using the null pointer in statements

```
    scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
```

and

```
    printf("The value of %d element is : %d\n", i, ptr[i]);
```

Move these statements

```
     free(ptr); 
     ptr = 0;
```

form the for loop to the end of the program before the return statement.

Comment: After we close the program, does the pointer automatically free itself or still retains it's value? Someone suggested me that we don't always has to free the pointers.

Comment: @Miraz When a process ends normally its resources  are returned to the system.

Answer (score 0):

`free(ptr);` is for freeing memory **you don't need any longer**. `ptr = 0;` is for inducing an access violation once some place accesses `ptr` despite it being freed and for a subsequent `free()` to not cause any errors.

In your case, what you do is way too early: you access it afterwards.

If you wanted to add it to a loop (for proving the assignment = 0 works as it should), you should add it to a new loop. This first loop isn't suitable, and the 2nd one isn't as well (because it outputs the data), but you should either add a 3rd loop or just do it manually:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(6 * sizeof(int)); // This. Don't cast to (int *), it can shadow errors.
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the value of %d element is :", i);
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
        // Don't free() it yet! We still use it.
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("The value of %d element is : %d\n", i, ptr[i]);
        // Don't free() it yet! We still use it in this loop.
    }

    // Now we can free it:
    free(ptr); 
    // Set it to 0 for not accidentally writing into memory we aren't allowed any longer and for alloing further free() calls with this pointer's content.
    ptr = 0;

    // Accidentally calling free() again doesn't do any harm any longer, as free(NULL) is a NOP.
    free(ptr); 
    ptr = 0; // redundant

    return 0;
}
```